# C# filter a list by a different list ("or")

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a book list:

```
List<Book> myBooks = new List<Book> {
   new Book {Name="Harry Potter 1",    Tags = new List<int>{2,4,10} },
   new Book {Name="The Little Prince", Tags = new List<int>{1,10}   },
   new Book {Name="Peter Pan",         Tags = new List<int>{3,5,10} },
   new Book {Name="Jungle Book",       Tags = new List<int>{1,4,3}  }
}
```

Now the user wants to filter all the books with tags [1,3,5] - meaning all the books that contains **at least** on of the tags. In this case, The user will get "The Little Prince" (tag #1),  "Peter Pan" (tags #3, #5) and "Jungle Book" (tags #1, #3) - but not "Harry Potter 1".

I have a function the gets a list of `int` tags, and can access the books.

Is there an elegant way to filter it nicely in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@GSerg said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643599/c-sharp-filter-a-list-by-a-different-list-or#comment121312457_68643599):

```
myBooks.Where(b => b.Tags.Any(t => tags.Contains(t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also ask if the intersection of the search tags and the book tags has more than zero items i.e do `myBooks.Where(b => tags.Intersect(b.Tags).Any());` which I find more readable, but for low numbers of tags on a book or in the search it's probably less resource intensive to use a method that gives up early (the AnyContains) if it finds X in Y

If you're going to do it a lot, you can build an index (once, and keep it/update it when you add/remove a book. Don't build it every time you search):

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, Book>();
foreach(var b in books)
  foreach(var t in b.Tags){
    if(d.TryGetValue(t, out var lst))
      lst.Add(b);
    else 
      d[t] = new List<Book>() { b };
  }
```

Now you can just ask for eg `d[0]` and get a List of Book that have tag 0

Or with LINQ

```
var d = books.SelectMany(b => b.Tag, (b,t) => new { Book=b, Tag=t}).GroupBy(bt => bt.Tag).ToDictionary();
```